# Issue overriding bootstrap CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have setup a `child theme` in WordPress and enqueued `/style.css` and `/inc/css/bootstrap.min.css` as these are the 2 style sheets I am amending from the parent theme:

```
function my_theme_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_styles', 99 );
```

It appears though, that when I put the amendment in the `bootstrap.min.css` file, it still loads the data from the parent `bootstrap.min.css`.

I have tried adding !important to the end, and also even added the CSS to the `footer.php` file to see if that would override it, but to no avail.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

SOLVED: I am a bit of a muppet. In the child bootstrap.min.css file, I was putting background-color: none on an element, when in the parent bootstrap.min.css it had a background color. I had to put transparent instead of none.

Comment: I've had issues like this before and most of the time it relates to cache either in your machine or the server, have you tried clearing every possible cache and verifying if your changes show up? you can read more about it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens)

Comment: @ArmandoBracho thanks for replying. I have just cleared browser cache, refreshed and still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact it's already solved, I'll leave here an advice: In cases like these a better solution is dequeuing the parent CSS file with

```
wp_dequeue_style( $handle );
```

The way it was solved by OP works, but dequeuing the file will result in a slightly better performance :)